# Automatically highlight certain words in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I want to highlight specific words (names of people in this case) in different colors. Ideally automatically, but even doing it manually (in bulk) would be okay.
Is this possible somehow? If not, what would you recommend as a solution?

Example:
(Imagine similar lines occuring hundreds of times in the document).

[image: "Mads will call the support, and Joon will make the graphics"]

Comment: Supposedly this can be done in Notepad ++ by using user defined languages, but the instructions on its website are for an old version.

Comment: This question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out [tour], [ask] and [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/88163). Note question that asks for a software recommendation is better suited for [softwarerecs.se]. Before asking a question on that site, please check out their tour and `/help/how-to-ask` docs.